# Javascript redirect url after form submit with parameter

Tags: javascript, forms

Im on trouble on redirect to subdomain. My goal is to send total value to my subdomain. Let me show you my form

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
   <div class="input-field">
      <p class="flow-text">Item yg dipesan...</p>
      <p>
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chkall" onclick="checkAll(this)">
         <span>Pilih Semua</span>
         </label>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="10000">
         <span>Item 1</span>
         </label>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="20000">
         <span>Item 2</span>
         </label>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="30000">
         <span>Item 3</span>
         </label>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="40000">
         <span>Item 4</span>
         </label>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="input-field">
      <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="getSum()">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is the js

```
 function getSum() {
    totalvalue = 0
    obj = document.myform.chkbox
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].checked) {
            totalvalue += parseInt(obj[i].value)
        }

    }

    if (totalvalue == 0) {
        alert("Please select atleast one product!!");
    } else {
        var url= "subdomain.domainname.com/cgi-bin/sale.cgi?cashflow="+totalvalue+"&secret=secretword"; 
        window.location.href = url;
    }

}

function checkAll(obj) {
    if (obj.checked) {
        obj = document.myform.chkbox
        for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj[i].checked = true
        }
    } else {
        obj = document.myform.chkbox
        for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj[i].checked = false
        }
    }

}
```

Let say that my domain name is `domainname.com` i try to redirect to `subdomain.domainname.com/cgi-bin/sale.cgi?cashflow="+totalvalue+"&secret=secretword` after submit button pressed. I expect the final url look like this `subdomain.domainname.com/cgi-bin/sale.cgi?cashflow=100000&secret=secretword`

The current result display final url like this `domainname.com/subdomain.domainname.com/cgi-bin/sale.cgi?cashflow=100000&secret=secretword`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `location.href` redirects to sub-url. Simply add `http://` to make absolute redirect:

```
var url= "http://subdomain.domainname.com/cgi-bin/sale.cgi?cashflow="+totalvalue+"&secret=secretword";
```